# set global variable command for foreach loop

Tags: macros, foreach, variable, csname

How can I set variable definition as a global variable to use it outside the eachfor loop?

```
\newcommand\Var[3]{ 
 \expandafter\edef\csname #1\Roman{#2}\endcsname{#3}
 }
\newcounter{count}
\foreach \i in {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}{
\stepcounter{count}
\Var{var}{count}{\Alph{count}}
}
```

\varII ???

Comment: `\expandafter\xdef\csname #1\Roman{#2}\endcsname{#3}`, i.e. `\xdef` instead of `\edef`. It is, however, not necessarily a good idea to make variables global.

Comment: You could just use `\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\Var[3]{ 
 \expandafter\edef\csname #1\Roman{#2}\endcsname{#3}
 }
\newcounter{count}
\setcounter{count}{0}
\loop
\stepcounter{count}
\Var{var}{count}{\Alph{count}}%
\ifnum\value{count}<10
\repeat
\begin{document}
\varIII
\end{document}`

Comment: The `\i` of the `\foreach`-loop is never used.  Seems instead of iterating on the comma-list `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9` for obtaining an amount of nine iterations, one could as well implement a loop where keeping track of the amount of iterations is done by counting/incrementing.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome! The answer to your question is: use `\xdef` instead of `\edef`, i.e.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\newcounter{count}
\newcommand\Var[3]{ 
 \expandafter\xdef\csname #1\Roman{#2}\endcsname{#3}
 }
\foreach \i in {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}{
\stepcounter{count}
\Var{var}{count}{\Alph{count}}
}
\begin{document}
\varIII
\end{document}
```

However, you do not need to make the variable global. Rather, you can use the built-in `\loop` for that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\Var[3]{ 
 \expandafter\edef\csname #1\Roman{#2}\endcsname{#3}
 }
\newcounter{count}
\setcounter{count}{0}
\loop
\stepcounter{count}
\Var{var}{count}{\Alph{count}}%
\ifnum\value{count}<10
\repeat
\begin{document}
\varIII
\end{document}
```

Comment: thx for ur reply, but I had tried xdef and it didn't work as ! Undefined control sequence. Further I want to use eachfor loop for another complicated loop and it just is a simple example.

Comment: @HadiEntezari I posted a full code, which works.

Comment: thx for ur kindness, the point was calling the right package.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `xparse`; I assume your values are not consecutive integers. I added an optional number to change the list separator in case you need commas in the values.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\setvariables}{mO{,}m}
 {% #1 = prefix for the variable name
  % #2 = separator (optional, default comma)
  % #3 list of values
  \hadi_setvariables:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \hadi_setvariables:nnn
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { #2 } { #3 }
  \seq_indexed_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq
   {% ##1 is the current index, ##2 is the current item
    \tl_set:cn { #1 \int_to_Roman:n { ##1 } } { ##2 }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\setvariables{var}{1,2,3,9,5.2}

\varI \quad \varII \quad \varIII \quad \varIV \quad \varV

\setvariables{xyz}[;]{1;0.1;a,b}

\xyzI \quad \xyzII \quad \xyzIII

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With pgffor's/TikZ's `\foreach` each iteration takes place within its own local scope. Non-global assignments (e.g., in terms of `\edef`) which take place within an iteration are restricted to that iteration's local scope.

Be aware that when using the LaTeX 2ε-kernel's `\@for` instead of pgffor's/TikZ's `\foreach`, iterations do not take place within a new local scope. Therefore with the LaTeX 2ε-kernel's `\@for` you don't need `\xdef` but can use `\edef`—can be something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{count}
\newcommand\Var[3]{%
  \expandafter\edef\csname #1\Roman{#2}\endcsname{#3}%
}%
\setcounter{count}{0}%
\@for\i:=0001,0010,0011,0100,0101,0110,0111,1000,1001\do{%
  \stepcounter{count}%
  \Var{var}{count}{Alphabetic: \Alph{count}--Binary: \i}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent
\verb|\varI|: \varI \\
\verb|\varII|: \varII \\
\verb|\varIII|: \varIII \\
\verb|\varIV|: \varIV \\
\verb|\varV|: \varV \\
\verb|\varVI|: \varVI \\
\verb|\varVII|: \varVII \\
\verb|\varVIII|: \varVIII \\
\verb|\varIX|: \varIX \\
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

You use `\Roman{⟨LaTeX counter⟩}` and `\Alph{⟨LaTeX counter⟩}`.

If you instead use `\@Roman{⟨TeX number quantity⟩}` and `\@Alph{⟨TeX number quantity⟩}`, you can do without count-registers.

In case ε-TeX-extensions are not available you may need to implement a routine for expandable incrementing:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Expandable incrementing of natural number formed by a sequence of
% explicit catcode-12-character-tokens-from-the-set {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
%..............................................................................
% \Increment{<natural number k as sequence of explicit catcode-12-character-
%             tokens from the set 0123456789>}
% ->
% <natural number (k+1) as sequence of explicit catcode-12-character-tokens
%  from the set 0123456789>
% In expansion-contexts the result is delivered after two expansion-steps/is 
% obtained by "hitting" \Increment with \expandafter twice.
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand\Increment[1]{%
  \romannumeral0%
  \UD@IncrementReverse{\UD@IncrementFork{}}{\relax}{}#1\relax
}%
\newcommand\UD@IncrementReverse[4]{%
  \ifx\relax#4%
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {#1#3#2}{\UD@IncrementReverse{#1}{#2}{#4#3}}%
}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@IncrementSelect{%
  \long\def\UD@IncrementSelect#10123456789\relax#2#3!!{#2}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@IncrementFork[2]{%
  \UD@IncrementSelect
  #2123456789\relax{\UD@IncrementReverse{ }{}{}#11}%
  0#223456789\relax{\UD@IncrementReverse{ }{}{}#12}%
  01#23456789\relax{\UD@IncrementReverse{ }{}{}#13}%
  012#2456789\relax{\UD@IncrementReverse{ }{}{}#14}%
  0123#256789\relax{\UD@IncrementReverse{ }{}{}#15}%
  01234#26789\relax{\UD@IncrementReverse{ }{}{}#16}%
  012345#2789\relax{\UD@IncrementReverse{ }{}{}#17}%
  0123456#289\relax{\UD@IncrementReverse{ }{}{}#18}%
  01234567#29\relax{\UD@IncrementReverse{ }{}{}#19}%
  012345678#2\relax{\UD@IncrementFork{#10}}%
  0123456789#2{\UD@IncrementReverse{ }{}{}#11\relax}%
  0123456789\relax{\UD@IncrementReverse{ }{}{}#11#2}%
  !!%
}%
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand\VarLoop[4]{%
  \ifnum#2<\expandafter\@firstofone\expandafter{\number#1} %
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi{%
    \expandafter\edef\csname#3\@Roman{#1}\endcsname{#4{#1}}%
    %\expandafter\show\csname#3\@Roman{#1}\endcsname%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\VarLoop
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\Increment{#1}}{#2}{#3}{#4}%
  }%
}%
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\VarLoop{1}{9}{var}{\@Alph}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent
\verb|\varI|: \varI \\
\verb|\varII|: \varII \\
\verb|\varIII|: \varIII \\
\verb|\varIV|: \varIV \\
\verb|\varV|: \varV \\
\verb|\varVI|: \varVI \\
\verb|\varVII|: \varVII \\
\verb|\varVIII|: \varVIII \\
\verb|\varIX|: \varIX \\
\end{document}
```

[image]

In case ε-TeX-extensions are available you can use `\number\numexpr...\relax` for expandable incrementing:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand\VarLoop[4]{%
  \ifnum#2<\expandafter\@firstofone\expandafter{\number#1} %
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi{%
    \expandafter\edef\csname#3\@Roman{#1}\endcsname{#4{#1}}%
    %\expandafter\show\csname#3\@Roman{#1}\endcsname%
    \expandafter\VarLoop
    \expandafter{\number\numexpr\number#1+1\relax}{#2}{#3}{#4}%
  }%
}%
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\VarLoop{1}{9}{var}{\@Alph}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent
\verb|\varI|: \varI \\
\verb|\varII|: \varII \\
\verb|\varIII|: \varIII \\
\verb|\varIV|: \varIV \\
\verb|\varV|: \varV \\
\verb|\varVI|: \varVI \\
\verb|\varVII|: \varVII \\
\verb|\varVIII|: \varVIII \\
\verb|\varIX|: \varIX \\
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

By the way:

Seems you use `\Roman` for converting digits into character-tokens of category code 11 (letter) which can occur in names of control word tokens like `\varI`, `\varII`, etc.

Did you know that via `\csname..\endcsname` you can have (La)TeX construct tokens whose names contain digits?

E.g.,

`\csname varI\endcsname` yields the control-word-token `\varI`.

In the same way

`\csname var1\endcsname` yields the control-word-token `\var1`.

You cannot type `\var1` directly in .tex-input-files as the reading-and-tokenizing-apparatus of (La)TeX would tokenize as
`\varcontrol word token` and `1explicit character token of category code 12(other)`.

But `\csname var1\endcsname` is read and tokenized as follows:

1. `\csnamecontrol word token`
2. `vexplicit character token of category code 11(letter)`
3. `aexplicit character token of category code 11(letter)`
4. `rexplicit character token of category code 11(letter)`
5. `1explicit character token of category code 12(other)`
6. `\endcsnamecontrol word token`

In the next stage, at the time of expanding things, the tokens that form the `\csname..\endcsname`-expression get expanded and the result of expanding `\csname...` is the token `\var1control word token`.

There is this nice special feature in (La)TeX, called `#{`-notation which lets you define macros whose last argument is delimited by `{`.

You can define a command

`\name⟨stuff without braces⟩{⟨ControlSequenceName⟩}`

which (after two expansion-steps) yields:

`⟨stuff without braces⟩\ControlSequenceName`

You can use it like:

`\name{Var23}` → `\Var23`
`\name\newcommand{Var23}...` → `\newcommand\Var23...`
`\name\global\long\def{Var23}...` → `\global\long\def\Var23...`
`\name\show{Var23}` → `\show\Var23`
`\name\meaning{Var23}` → `\meaning\Var23`
`\name\name\let{Var23}={Var24}` → `\name\let\Var23={Var24}` → `\let\Var23=\Var24`

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{scratchcounter}

% Let's define the \name-macro:

\makeatletter
\newcommand\exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\@ifdefinable\name{\long\def\name#1#{\romannumeral0\innername{#1}}}%
\newcommand\innername[2]{\expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{ #1}}%
\makeatother

% Let's define "variables/macros" \var1..\var9 in a loop:

\setcounter{scratchcounter}{0}%
\loop
  \stepcounter{scratchcounter}%
  \name\name{@ifdefinable}{var\number\value{scratchcounter}}{%
    \name\edef{var\number\value{scratchcounter}}{\Alph{scratchcounter}}%
  }%
\ifnum\value{scratchcounter}<9
\repeat

% Let's define the macro \foo45/c-;/bar

\name\newcommand*{foo45/c-;/bar}{This is a macro with a weird name.}

\parindent=0ex

\begin{document}
\verb|\name{var1}|: $\to$ \texttt{\name\string{var1}} $\to$ \name{var1} \\
\verb|\name{var2}|: $\to$ \texttt{\name\string{var2}} $\to$ \name{var2} \\
\verb|\name{var3}|: $\to$ \texttt{\name\string{var3}} $\to$ \name{var3} \\
\verb|\name{var4}|: $\to$ \texttt{\name\string{var4}} $\to$ \name{var4} \\
\verb|\name{var5}|: $\to$ \texttt{\name\string{var5}} $\to$ \name{var5} \\
\verb|\name{var6}|: $\to$ \texttt{\name\string{var6}} $\to$ \name{var6} \\
\verb|\name{var7}|: $\to$ \texttt{\name\string{var7}} $\to$ \name{var7} \\
\verb|\name{var8}|: $\to$ \texttt{\name\string{var8}} $\to$ \name{var8} \\
\verb|\name{var9}|: $\to$ \texttt{\name\string{var9}} $\to$ \name{var9} \\
\verb|\name{foo45/c-;/bar}|: $\to$ \texttt{\name\string{foo45/c-;/bar}}  $\to$ \name{foo45/c-;/bar}

\hrulefill\null

Now let's redefine \verb|\var8|:

\verb|\name\renewcommand{var8}[1]{Now we have a macro which processes an argument: #1}|\\
$\to$\\
\verb|\renewcommand\var8[1]{Now we have a macro which processes an argument: #1}|\\
\name\renewcommand{var8}[1]{Now we have a macro which processes an argument: #1}

\verb|\name\string{var8}: \name\meaning{var8}| yields:

\begingroup
\ttfamily\frenchspacing
\hbox{%
\name\string{var8}: \name\meaning{var8}%
}%
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]